# When i integrate Facebook SDK it shows error

Tags: android

Error:(15, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':facebook'.

> Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':facebook'.

Comment: try this sdk for facebook.. dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
}

Answer (score 0):

"There is also a GUI way for doing this. It is accessed by selecting the module facebook in the project tree and pressing f4.

Also you can just right-click the facebook and go to Open Module Settings near the bottom."

Source : mdzeko (StackOverflow)

And then you can set the build sdk version.